# BSOD after new Nvidia driver installing

Tags: windows-7, boot, drivers, bsod

Nvidia has recently released a new driver (.43) that has corrupted express installation. I'm not entirely sure that it was exactly this version, but it was working just fine to me. Yesterday i've got a new update (through Experience, Beta turned off), double checked that it is a stable .51 version and installed it using custom install.

Everything was fine untill the first reboot. Login screen appears and this is where i've got BSOD. Is's cause was a `uncorrectable hardware error` (code 124).
I was able to boot in safe mode with network where i've deleted this driver using DDU but it kept showing BSOD. Then i've removed my `MSI GTX 660` and tried to boot using integrated video with the same result
I've tried RAM check and sfc - all clear. Also tried to boot from another HDD that has Windows 7 installed. This time i've got almost instant BSOD (`code 7B`) that told me to run CHKDSK (just tried it to my main disk, there was errors but it didnt help). But this is where I cant even get into a safe mode. Primary disk doesn't boot in safe mode either

Any help will be greatly appreciated and please excuse me for all the mistakes I've made.

**Update 1** To preserve my system and check if hardware is Ok I've just installed a new copy of Windows 7 at my second HDD (main one is actualy a SSD). It actually is working, .51 driver is in place and working too. BUT when I plugged SSD back, tried to boot, failed once more and booted new system back mouse and keyboard have stopped working. Even Safe mode is broken

Comment: Sounds like your major problems are your HDD not a driver problem.  Once you get your system back be sure to avoid beta releases, and avoid installing drivers, through Nvidia Experience.  You should always use wipe the previous version before you install the next version.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your response. I've updated my question. I feel that the motherboard is responsible in some way but i dont know how to check it properly

Comment: If another HDD boots, and the system works, their isn't the motherboard.  You mention chkdsk errors, unless you provide those, we can't comment on them